# How to reset MariaDB into a "fresh install" state?

Tags: mariadb

I had InnoDB corruption and managed to start the server in read only mode and perform a fresh backup using `innodb_force_recovery=5`.

This way of starting the service puts the databases in read only mode, even deletion is disallowed.

Is there an official procedure to reset the whole server into a fresh installed (or at least "empty") version?

And in case there isn't, then what are the correct uninstall/reinstall steps to make sure there will be no remaining residues of data that could generate problems in the future?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MariaDB can be reverted to the fresh state by removing its data files.

Say if you run MariaDB on a Debian you can do the next:

```
systemctl stop mysql
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
systemctl start mysql
```

At the start if no datafiles exists MariaDB will recreate the internal scheme `mysql.*` with all default values. All leftovers like config and log files you have to clean up by hands.

Comment: Maybe this is different on Debian, but I think you have to run `mysql_install_db` before you start it up again - at least that is my experience on Redhat/Fedora/CentOS.

Comment: @dbdemon On debian and freebsd (at least) start scripts invoke it automatically if no system db was found at datadir

Comment: My Debain 11 did not automatically invoke mysql_install_db .  It is easy enough to check: ls /var/lib/mysql/mysql .  If there is no directory it didn't run.

Comment: On debian 10, I called `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.3.postinst configure` to recreate "mysql" database

Comment: Thanks @dbdemon -- I forgot about `mysql_install_db` and MariaDB didn't want to start on macOS for me. After running the command it went on fine.